# How to use CNN Keras model in android studio for mobile application

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, keras

I am new to Machine Learning. I trained model on 2 classes and got 82% accuracy. I saved this model with `model.save()`. I searched on internet about how to use this keras trained model in android studio for mobile application but i didn't understand anything. Can anyone tell me what should i do to use this trained model in android studio. This is the model of CNN i used:

```
model= Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
)
```

This is the summary of my model:

```
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)           (None, 148, 148, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_26 (Activation)   (None, 148, 148, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_16 (MaxPooling (None, 74, 74, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)           (None, 72, 72, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_27 (Activation)   (None, 72, 72, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_17 (MaxPooling (None, 36, 36, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)           (None, 34, 34, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_28 (Activation)   (None, 34, 34, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_18 (MaxPooling (None, 17, 17, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 18496)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 64)                1183808   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_29 (Activation)   (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 65        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_30 (Activation)   (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,259,521
Trainable params: 1,259,521
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find examples in the documentation link [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter?hl=tr-TR&skip_cache=true)
after saving the model run the following

**EDIT**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
# Converting a SavedModel to a TensorFlow Lite model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Converting a tf.Keras model to a TensorFlow Lite model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Converting ConcreteFunctions to a TensorFlow Lite model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([func])
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

Comment: Sir this, code will directly change the keras code to tensorflow lite or should i change it first to tensorflow then to tensorflow lite?

Comment: you should first run `model.save()` which will create the directory used in the snippet above. check the docs for more information

Comment: Sir i tried this code. I put the location of directory of my file in in the ```saved_model_dir``` and got this error. can you please tell me what to change in this code? The error i got is this: OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: Munib\3_layer_model_try3/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the way to convert from keras model to tflite which is your case. in the case of saved models note that you should pass the directory not the file.

Comment: Sorry sir for late message. I put my trained model file in a folder name "New folder". i got this error again: ``` OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: C:\Users\Munib\New folder/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

Comment: as i said you should pass the directory not the file. try replacing `C:\Users\Munib\New folder\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}` with `C:\Users\Munib\New folder`

Comment: Sir i send the location like this:```saved_model_dir = r"C:\Users\Munib\New folder" ``` and got the error i mentioned above.

Comment: I know this thread got a bit long and I am sorry but could you tell me how did you save the model? and if you could share the directory tree that would be awesome

Comment: Sir, i saved the model with name: ``` model.save('3_layer_model_try3')``` and the directory where i saved this model is: ``` C:\Users\Munib\New folder ``` .

Comment: Ok i think i got it now, model.save will create a directory for you with this name `3_layer_model_try3` , inside this directory there should be a file with the `pb` or `pbtxt` extension, this is the directory you should pass to the tflite converter, I believe it would be `saved_model_dir = r"C:\Users\Munib\New folder\3_layer_model_try3"`

Comment: No sir when i put model.save() command i just created one one file with name ``` 3_layer_model_try3 ```.

Comment: the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) says it creates a directory not a file, are you sure ?

Comment: Sir, i am also now confused can you send me your email or something where i can share image with you about my code so you can tell me the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215906/discussion-between-mirza-munib-and-mahmoud-youssef).